# Ubuntu LiveUSB boot options not working

Tags: 14.04, acer, aspire

I am using Rufus to create Ubuntu LiveUSB stick. Laptop is an Acer Aspire R11.  I had 12.04 available. I downloaded 14.04, and I am in the process of downloading 16.04.

On my first try I got the error:

```
IO-APIC + timer doesn't work ... Try booting with the 'noapic' option
```

12.04: selecting `noapic` just gave me a blank screen. However, when I set `acpi=off`, it booted successfully. Unfortunately, I found out that 12.04 doesn't support my WiFi. Forums state 15.10 or later required.

In the meantime, 14.04 downloaded (still waiting on 16.04 SLOW connection here... May take a day). I decided to try it. In 14.04, Even when I set `noapic` and/or `acpi=off`, I still get the same message! I find it odd that I can even get this message with the noapic option set. Though I'm getting 16.04, I'm concerned this may still be an issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying 16.04 anyway, it's better that you wait. It'd be pretty pointless to go through a whole troubleshooting process to have it all fixed by installing another version of Ubuntu

Comment: Not expecting a whole troubleshooting process, was hoping maybe someone might see it and say oh, yeah, that's a known bug and the workaround is this...

Comment: I can't find anyone who has the problem on 14.04 or later. What did you use to Install? Disc or USB?

Comment: It's not installed, running on a liveUSB, attempting "try ubuntu before installing" using F6 boot options trying to boot. USB stick was created using Rufus and release ISOs from Ubuntu

Comment: Figured it out, and posted answer to my own question. Starting with version 14, Ubuntu processes the command line different. On some machines it is necessary to put the startup entries both before and after the -- delimiter. Not only did this work, but despite other forum posts to the contrary, 14.04.4 did detect and used my Wifi unlike 12.04, so I'm up and running. I have another issue now, but I'll save that for a new post.

Comment: FYI. Still need this in Lubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

After pressing F6, manually edit the command line that appears to add acpi=off (or whatever boot options are necessary for other people) before AND after the -- delimiter